# Dask force kill all workers

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I want to force kill all the `dask-worker` processes connected to my `dask.distributed` scheduler. I am NOT running the cluster locally, it is a distributed cluster.

I have tried the following:

```
workers = scheduler.workers_to_close(n=num_workers)
scheduler.retire_workers(workers=workers,close_workers=True,remove=True)
```

Here, `num_workers` is known beforehand. 
However, this doesn't seem to work. Sometimes, no workers are killed whereas sometimes, only one worker is killed. Am I doing this incorrectly? Is there a better/correct way to do this?

Comment: I do have the same issue. I wonder if it's due to the underlying slurm cluster scancel command sometimes timing out, although this seems unlikely. What's weird is that even though some workers stays alive, they disappear from the client.scheduler_info()['workers'] dictionary while staying visible within the dashboard.

Comment: Edit: I am not sure it relies on internal scancel command on the scheduler node rather than network communication to the worker node.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems fine to me.  I recommend making a minimal example and then raising an issue on github